# Dynamically linked library cannot be found in cross-compilation

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, embedded-linux

I've been trying to dynamically link a shared object with a binary. Everything is fine until I try to run it, which gives me:

```
/tmp/test: error while loading shared libraries: libxl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

also ldd shows that the file cannot be found. Of course, the library in question is in the default location (/lib/arm-linux/gnueabihf). I have also run ldconfig after library was copied there.

I have checked following things:

- set rpath to include the location
- set LD_LIBRARY_PATH with correct location
- created a dummy shared object with the same name - it was found successfully (of course doesn't have necessary symbols)

The library is created as:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI4 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
```

while the test binary is:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
```

Can the EABI version cause those kind of problems with running? Is there anything else I can try to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

Library path must be the location of libraries in the HOST machine not the target machine. It seems that "/lib/arm-linux/gnueabihf" is the location of library in your target machine.

Find the correct path of libxl.so in your toolchain sysroot.

Comment: When I've created a mock library and placed it in the same location as the original one, it was found and loaded (there were no necessary symbols of course, so execution failed). The question then is whether the EABI version mismatch may cause such issues.